# Overlapping elements - Form in front, but cursor goes behind

Tags: html, css

I have a form with an input field. While the input field comes in front, the text cursor seems to go behind. I have tried various Z-index combinations, which don't help, as the object is already in front. How do I get the cursor in front? I know I'm doing something trivially wrong, but I'm not able to place it

**Code snippet:**

```css
.searchBox {
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
  border: medium none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 24px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 38.7%;
  z-index: 3000;
}

.searchIconBox {
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:49%;">
  <form style="width:94%;" class="pull-left">
    <input type="text" class="searchBox" placeholder="Search"></input>
  </form>
  <div class="pull-right searchIconBox">
    <asset:image src="search.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create one fiddle at JsFiddle

Comment: why are you setting z-index: 3000; 
?

Comment: Hi, I've made a jsfiddle with your code : https://jsfiddle.net/na3nnb76/
yet I can't reproduce the bug you're talking about. Do you ? What browser are you testing on ?

Answer (score 2):

The cursor isn't going behind. It is camouflaging with the color `#7e7e7e`

Try giving the color of

```
.searchBox{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

and then hover the cursor, you will see it is visible

Comment: why the unnecessary downvote? At least explain the reason

Comment: Thanks for the quick turn around! That was the issue indeed.

Comment: From what I read online, the cursor borrows the 'color' attribute (basically the font color). In which case, the cursor should have become white (color: #fff) and should still be visible in the grey background right?

Comment: Not the font color, but any color on which the cursor hovers. The color of the sections of the cursor which intersect the background will get inverted, for eg if background is #000, then the cursor will be #fff

Comment: I thought that inversion takes place only in IE?

Comment: The cursor is visible in your code too, open the magnifier and see carefully. I use chrome, the colors get inverted. For example 0 for 255, 1 for 254, 2 for 253...and so on. What happened in your case was something like 127 for 128 therefore it got camouflaged. It is still visible though

Comment: If my answer is correct, then kindly mark it. It is against the rules to thank anyone here

Comment: Tried up-voting yesterday; I need at least 15 reputation points for that. I'm new to SO, so you'll have to bare with me till I do manage to get them :).

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me, there just isn't a convenient color for the cursor to change to with the gray of the search box.

Try something like...

```
.searchBox{background-color:#d0d0d0;}
```

and your cursor will be much more visible.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue (non-issue actually; I feel really stupid asking this now!). Thanks, that was quick!

Comment: From what I read online, the cursor borrows the 'color' attribute (basically the font color). In which case, the cursor should have become white (color: #fff) and should still be visible in the grey background right?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add more padding-left in .searchBox because cursor can starts after the icon:

```
   .searchBox { padding-left: 25px; }
```

If you need that searchBox doesn't expand to right, add box-sizing

```
   .searchBox { padding-left: 25px; box-sizing : border-box; }
```

Comment: Why unvote? it is frustating, receiving downvotes without explanation. Note that the problem that describes the user doesn't appears in Firefox 39, but with my solution solves the problem in all browsers

Comment: The padding doesn't seem to be the issue here, changing the background-color solved the problem.